# ExtJS4 stores for linkedin

Tags: javascript, extjs, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use ExtJS4 Stores to read my Linkedin connections and display my LinkedIn connections in a grid as per the tutorial at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture , however I'm not quite sure how to embed LinkedIn authentication token into the 'read' url in the [proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy) below.

Any idea ?

```
proxy: {
 type: 'ajax',
 api: {
     read: 'data/users.json',
     update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
 },
 reader: {
     type: 'json',
     root: 'users',
     successProperty: 'success'
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what the authentication token is supposed to look like?  Also, I don't see any POST parameter configuration in the code you have posted.

Comment: all linkedin gives me is api key and secret. i am not sure if i can programmatically retrieve the connections, also i'll find out if i can do POST using the proxy object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not cross domain post via AJAX proxy. You need the JSONP proxy instead.
You can set extraParams object on the proxy to always send the token with each request - if that is requirement. Sorry i have not had a chance to work with LinkedIn api.